# capistrano - ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

i try to deploy rails app with capistrano 3, pg database, nginx and passenger i have this error
i use RVM
os: ubuntu 14.04
ruby v: 2.1.4

full error http://ec2-52-38-245-69.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

```
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:71:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/bin/ri (Errno::EACCES)
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:71:in `open'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:71:in `block in try_to_fix_binstubs'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:69:in `map'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:69:in `try_to_fix_binstubs'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:46:in `block in execute_no_wrapper'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:44:in `execute_no_wrapper'
    from extconf.rb:19:in `<main>'
bundler 1.11.2
executable-hooks 1.3.2
rake 10.1.0
rdoc 4.1.0

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/executable-hooks-1.3.2/gem_make.out
 (Gem::Ext::BuildError)
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89:in `run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:38:in `block in build'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tempfile.rb:324:in `open'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:17:in `build'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:423:in `load_native_extension'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:113:in `load_from_load_path'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:40:in `try_load'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:50:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:439:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger.rb:235:in `require_passenger_lib'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:76:in `init_passenger'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:155:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Comment: *Permission denied*... Check the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the user that you are deploying as has the appropriate permissions to install gems. To verify this, log into the server as that user and try to install some gems from your `Gemfile`.

Some gems might fail to install if they are missing system dependencies such as openssl, libxml, etc.